# Jquery Slider Widget ui-slider-handle scale handle bar

Tags: javascript, slider

I am trying to change the size of the image for the ui slider handler to increase as you move the scroller to the right and to decrease in size as you scroll it to the left. I will be using a SVG of course so the scale remains accurate! any ideas? :(

Ye can check out the code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/3teR3/

or here:

```
    #slider {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 50px auto;

}
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
    width:28px; 
    height:28px; 
    background:url(http://hitskin.com/themes/13/67/44/i_right_arrow.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    overflow: hidden; 
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:0px;
    top: -7px;
    border-style:none;
    cursor:help;
}

 <div id="slider"></div>


$(function() {
    $("#slider").slider();
});
```

Comment: We have a good idea of what you want to do, but what exactly is your question?

Comment: I need to make the svg image increased in size as you move the slider so lets say the width and height of the image on the 25% at the start of the slider and every 50 steps the image would grow by 25%. I have this working but cant seem to do it with an image.
http://jsfiddle.net/5TTm4/625/ Ignore the red box :)

Comment: Did you try binding to the widget's [change](http://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar/#event-change) event and updating the image's size accordingly? Which problems did you encounter?

Comment: the svg images is not changing size accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the size of the .png dependent from width and height and change these with the slider-value:

HTML:

```
 <div id="slider"></div>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
}
  #slider {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
  .ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
  width:28px; 
  height:28px; 
  background:url(http://hitskin.com/themes/13/67/44/i_right_arrow.png) no-repeat 0 0;

  background-size:100%;  /*this is the importent thing!*/

  overflow: hidden; 
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:0px;
  top: -7px;
  border-style:none;
  cursor:help;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
  $("#slider").slider({    
    min:0, max: 10,
    slide: function(event,ui){
      $(".ui-slider-handle").css('width',28*(1+(ui.value)));
      $(".ui-slider-handle").css('height',28*(1+(ui.value)));
    },
  });
});
```

And here as jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1Blerk/3teR3/20/
Maybe it is still usefull for you.